# Why does webcall get success in every case when it should be failure/error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

HTML CODE

```
<h1 class="popup-title full-width no-margin padding-right source-border-bottom"><span>Enter Employee ID</span></h1>

    <div class="bar bar-subheader has-header-text no-border search-txt modal-side-align-search">
            <label class="item item-input no-padding no-border asda-txtbox-border search-label txt-box-border">
                <input type="search" resizepopup class="txt-box search-txtbox" placeholder="Search with keyword..." ng-model="employeeCode" ng-change="scrolltoTop()" ng-blur="fieldBlur()" id="searchSource" ng-keypress="searchEmployee($event)"> 

                <!--<i class="icon ion-search search-icon"></i> -->
                <img class="searchStyle" src="assets/images/search.png">
            </label>
    </div>
```

JS CODE

```
$scope.employeeCode = "";

var dataForService = {
            "authToken": "",
            empCode: ""
        }

$scope.searchEmployee = function(keyEvent){

            if (keyEvent.which === 13)
            {
            console.log("The employee code is "+$scope.employeeCode);

            UtilityFactory.showLoading();

            dataForService.authToken = authTok; // authTok is generated in another part of the program
            dataForService.empCode = $scope.employeeCode;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(dataForService)); 
            Factory.webCallEmployee(dataForService).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                var response = data;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                console.log(response.employee.employeeCode);

                if (response.responseStatus === "success") {
                    $timeout(function() {
                            UtilityFactory.hideLoading();
                    }, 2000); 
                }
                else{     
                    UtilityFactory.hideLoading();
                    console.log('This employee is not present in our records');      
                    $ionicPopup.alert({     
                        title: 'Error',     
                        template: 'This employee is not present in our records'        
                    }).then(function(res) {     
                            console.log('Error in else block');            
                    });     
                }                       
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {      
                alert(status);      
                UtilityFactory.hideLoading();             
                $ionicPopup.alert({     
                    title: 'Error',     
                    template: 'Error statement'      
                });     
            }); 

            }
        }
```

JSON DATA

```
{
"responseStatus":"success",
"employee":{
   "employeeCode":"E001",
   "employeeName":"ABC",
   "employeeMobileNo":"1234567890",
   "comCode":"0000029558",
   "comName":"Digital Mirror",
   "deptCode":"HR"
}
```

}

I have a factory , from which I am getting the correct response status , for learning sake I am using hard-coded JSON data instead of real service  but I have one issue -

1. In my JSON data the only hardcoded employee no is E001 , but I enter any other value it should go to the error block & give me an error , it is always entering the success block , I mean to say if the employee is not E001 , if i enter say Tom as Employee No , it should go the error block but it is not happening

Also if the employee is present I want to display this employee is present , other "Sorry this employee is not available"

[image: image1]

Please refer the image to find what I am to do

Comment: remove CSS from the tag list

Comment: you can remove it but the problem is not due to CSS

Comment: @Hidayt Rahman problem is that it is entering the success block even when my employee code is not E001 , if I give your name as code it should go to error block

Comment: I am saying about the question, this is not related to CSS

Comment: yes i have done that

Comment: Do not put tags in your title @scooby123

Comment: i will remove rob , i did a mistake , i am a newbie , kindly help me with my issue if you can

Comment: Show the code for `Factory.webCallEmployee`. There is probably a rejection handler that is converting the rejected promise to a fulfilled promise.